# Transparent authentication with LDAP and Servlet

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets, ldap

We have Windows Active Directory, where all users are registered and use to login in Windows.

We have an Apache server configured to use LDAP to authenticate users in that Active Directory. It's setup so that, in PHP, all we have to do is call `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`. Browser verifies user login in Windows and sends this data to Apache, which talks to LDAP to verify authentication. When LDAP authenticates, that code returns user's login, otherwise it returns null.

This way we can safely and easily authenticate users inside PHP and use their AD login to control access to our softwares. Another advantage is that we don't need a login page and not even have to handle passwords in variables: authentication is handled transparently to users and they are automatically logged to our softwares all the time, and their password never comes into our code.

I'd like to do the same thing with Servlet. I see no reason for it not happen if it works with PHP. But I can't find how to do it. I googled but couldn't find anything. Has anybody done something like that and could point me a way?

Standard authentication with login and password is working in Java. If I have domain, login and password, (that in Servlet would come from a login page) I can authenticate any user.

Comment: THan ks guys! I found a component named spnegro that enabes getRemoteUser() to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking to do is plug a SSO provider into your web app. There are several options, you will have to do your own research into what will work best in your environment. You might want to investigate the following security frameworks, which all enable SSO:

- [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)
- [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)
- [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/)

There are also commercial products like CA SiteMinder that do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

the HttpServletRequest object you have in the doGet and doPost methods on the servlet has the equivalent of PHP `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`, it is called [getRemoteUser()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Your post is tagged as Tomcat. You could add a "realm" in tomcat to do the Authentication.

I have no idea how you can not prompt for a password unless you are using some sort of SASL plugin to verify the user against LDAP.

$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] implies you are using "HTTP Authentication" header which would (AFIK) require a popup for the credentials. Perhaps this is transparent if only using IE against a Windows server.

There is [an example of how to configure tomcat](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP)

Comment: It works with FireFox too. Unfortunately IDK how Apache is configured for it to work because I don't have access to it, but any PHP code that calls `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` receives his AD login. In rare situations FireFox shows a popup for login.

Comment: If you are getting a "browser", it is a basic auth request form the server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication/